# Online Accounts on 16.10 - only few options

Tags: 16.10, online-accounts, accounts

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.10 on my desktop and for whatever reason the options offered for adding accounts from the **Online Accounts** section of the **System Settings** are kind of sparse.

Here's what I expect to see:
[All earlier available options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlsZ0.png)
Here's what I actually see:
[Facebook / Flickr and Google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fau57.png)

I can't seem to find a similar issue reported on Ask Ubuntu. Can anybody point me to the right direction for trying to figure out why my options are so sparse, or is this the way it should be?

***System Information***

Ubuntu 16.10 Yakkety Yak - 64-bit
Intel® Core™ i7-6700K 4.00 GHz × 8
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080/PCIe/SSE2

Please ask for more details if needed.

Comment: It is how it should be in 16.10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are still many more Online Accounts available in Ubuntu 16.10, but only some of them are installed by default, most probably because they are the most used ones. To check which Online Accounts are available to connect with Ubuntu, just open a terminal and execute this command :

`apt search account-plugin`

```
$ apt search account-plugin
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
account-plugin-aim/yakkety 3.12.12-3ubuntu1 amd64
  Messaging account plugin for AIM

account-plugin-facebook/yakkety,yakkety 0.13+16.10.20160929.1-0ubuntu1 all
  Online account plugin for Unity - Facebook

account-plugin-fitbit/yakkety,yakkety 4 all
  Allow Ubuntu to access FitBit data

account-plugin-flickr/yakkety,yakkety 0.13+16.10.20160929.1-0ubuntu1 all
  Online account plugin for Unity - Flickr

account-plugin-foursquare/yakkety,yakkety 0.13+16.10.20160929.1-0ubuntu1 all
  Online account plugin for Unity - FourSquare

account-plugin-gadugadu/yakkety 3.12.12-3ubuntu1 amd64
  Messaging account plugin for GaduGadu

account-plugin-google/yakkety,yakkety,now 0.13+16.10.20160929.1-0ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
  Online account plugin for Unity - Google

account-plugin-groupwise/yakkety 3.12.12-3ubuntu1 amd64
  Messaging account plugin for Groupwise

account-plugin-icq/yakkety 3.12.12-3ubuntu1 amd64
  Messaging account plugin for ICQ

account-plugin-identica/yakkety,yakkety 0.13+16.10.20160929.1-0ubuntu1 all
  Online account plugin for Unity - identi.ca

account-plugin-instagram/yakkety,yakkety 0.13+16.10.20160929.1-0ubuntu1 all
  Online account plugin for Unity - Instagram

account-plugin-irc/yakkety 3.12.12-3ubuntu1 amd64
  Messaging account plugin for IRC

account-plugin-jabber/yakkety 3.12.12-3ubuntu1 amd64
  Messaging account plugin for Jabber/XMPP

account-plugin-linkedin/yakkety,yakkety 0.13+16.10.20160929.1-0ubuntu1 all
  Online account plugin for Unity - LinkedIn

account-plugin-mcloud/yakkety,yakkety 0.13+16.10.20160929.1-0ubuntu1 all
  Online account plugin for Unity - mCloud

account-plugin-mxit/yakkety 3.12.12-3ubuntu1 amd64
  Messaging account plugin for Mxit

account-plugin-myspace/yakkety 3.12.12-3ubuntu1 amd64
  Messaging account plugin for MySpace

account-plugin-owncloud/yakkety,yakkety 0.13+16.10.20160929.1-0ubuntu1 all
  Online account plugin for Unity - ownCloud

account-plugin-salut/yakkety 3.12.12-3ubuntu1 amd64
  Messaging account plugin for Local XMPP (Salut)

account-plugin-sametime/yakkety 3.12.12-3ubuntu1 amd64
  Messaging account plugin for Sametime

account-plugin-sina/yakkety,yakkety 0.13+16.10.20160929.1-0ubuntu1 all
  Online account plugin for Unity - Sina

account-plugin-sip/yakkety 3.12.12-3ubuntu1 amd64
  Messaging account plugin for SIP

account-plugin-sohu/yakkety,yakkety 0.13+16.10.20160929.1-0ubuntu1 all
  Online account plugin for Unity - Sohu

account-plugin-tools/yakkety,yakkety,now 0.13+16.10.20160929.1-0ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
  Online account plugins for Unity - tools

account-plugin-twitter/yakkety,yakkety 0.13+16.10.20160929.1-0ubuntu1 all
  Online account plugin for Unity - Twitter

account-plugin-ubuntuone/yakkety,now 15.11+16.10.20160920 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  Ubuntu One authentication library - account settings plug-in

account-plugin-vk/yakkety,yakkety 0.13+16.10.20160929.1-0ubuntu1 all
  Online account plugin for Unity - VKontakte

account-plugin-yahoo/yakkety 3.12.12-3ubuntu1 amd64
  Messaging account plugin for Yahoo!

account-plugin-yahoojp/yakkety 3.12.12-3ubuntu1 amd64
  Messaging account plugin for Yahoo Japan

account-plugin-zephyr/yakkety 3.12.12-3ubuntu1 amd64
  Messaging account plugin for Zephyr
```

You can install each Online Account by executing : `sudo apt install <account-plugin-name>`
Replace `<account-plugin-name>` with the package name - example : `account-plugin-jabber` When you open System Settings -> Online Accounts afterwards, the added accounts are visible.

Comment: Thanks, that´s much better! Out of curiosity, is this information readily available anywhere that I somehow missed?

Comment: @MikeyThanh : Yes, when you search for keyword `account-plugin` on the ubuntu packages website -> http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=account-plugin&searchon=names&suite=yakkety&section=all :)

Answer (score 0):

[@cl-netbox](https://askubuntu.com/users/260935/cl-netbox) answer is useful to identify all available online account plugins for Ubuntu, this function makes easy for anyone who want install specify account plugin. My answer just recall old control center and online accounts setting. (CMIIW)

If I remember correctly the old one uses `gnome-control-center` instead of `unity-control-center` and `gnome-online-accounts` for it's online accounts configuration:

```
sudo apt install gnome-control-center gnome-online-accounts
```

I suppose you might just want install the old control center for the sake of convenience

Comment: Just a little clarification and information :  `gnome-control-center` is installed and needed when the GNOME desktop environment is in use, such as it is the case when using Ubuntu GNOME. When you are using Ubuntu with the Unity desktop environment, `unity-control-center` is installed and needed, which means that `unity-control-center` is not a replacement for `gnome-control-center`. :)

Answer (score 0):

like @iTux wrote.
The All earlier available options is

```
gnome-online-accounts
```

that what you looking for. 
you need to run from terminal

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-online-accounts
```

then you will have two settings. choose setting (and not system settings).
there you will see online account with different icon.